# How to take a list of IDs from an array, match each item to the ID in the firestore, and return a JSON of the associated data to front-end site?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

Like the title says, I am trying to take a list of IDs from an array, match each ID to the ID in the firestore, and return an array of JSONs of the associated data to front-end site. The code below is returning an empty array.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.getPlayerDataFromTokens = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var db = admin.firestore();
    const tokens = data.tokens;
    let playerArray = [];
    tokens.forEach((token) => {
      const tokensToTokenData = db.collection("Football_Player_Data").where("Token", "==", token);
      tokensToTokenData.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            playerDataToken = doc.data()["Token"];
            playerDataJersey = doc.data()["Jersey_Number"];
            playerDataMultiplier = doc.data()["Multiplier"];
            playerDataPlayerID = doc.data()["PlayerID"];
            playerDataPosition = doc.data()["Position"];
            playerDataTeam = doc.data()["Team"];
            playerData = {
              "Token": playerDataToken,
              "PlayerID": playerDataPlayerID,
              "Jersey_Number": playerDataJersey,
              "Position": playerDataPosition,
              "Team": playerDataTeam,
              "Multiplier": playerDataMultiplier
            };
            playerArray.push(playerData);
            
        });

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        playerArray = error;
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error)
        reject(playerArray);
      });
    })
    resolve(JSON.stringify(playerArray));
  });
})
```

Comment: The best way to debug these is to try to `console.log` each piece. I'd start with `console.log({ tokensToTokenData })` to make sure that populates correctly. From there I'd try `console.log({ querySnapshot })`, `console.log({ playerArray })` and so on until you find which piece of code isn't populating. It's possible this function works just fine and you need to call `getPlayerDataFromTokens().then()`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you are building this based on a very outdated tutorial.

In Firebase Functions V1.0.0 (April 2018), `functions.config().firebase` was removed. It now resolves as `undefined` so that the modern `admin.initializeApp()` (with no arguments) functions properly. When invoked this way, the Admin SDK initializes based on the presence of the [appropriate environment variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-without-parameters).

Next, you are using the [Explicit Promise Construction Antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/3068190). In short, do not wrap your code inside `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})`.

As this functions code is likely to be deployed to Google Cloud Functions, which runs on Node 10/12/14 you can use modern ES2017 syntax like `async`/`await`, deconstruction patterns, `import`, `let`, `const` and `Promise.all`.

So this means the top of your script consists of:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

admin.initializeApp();
```

As you need to fetch a list of players for each token given, you can break this logic out into it's own function:

```
/**
 * For the given token, return an array of players linked with
 * that token.
 */
async function getFootballPlayersWithToken(db, token) {
  const playersWithTokenQuerySnapshot = await db
    .collection("Football_Player_Data")
    .where("Token", "==", token)
    .get();

  if (playersWithTokenQuerySnapshot.empty) {
    console.log("Given token did not match any players: ", token);
    return []; // or throw error
  }
  
  const playerArray = await Promise.all(
    playersWithTokenQuerySnapshot.docs
      .map((playerDoc) => {
        const { Token, Jersey_Number, Multiplier, PlayerID, Position, Team } = playerDoc.data();
        return { Token, Jersey_Number, Multiplier, PlayerID, Position, Team };
      });
  );
  
  return playerArray;
}
```

In the above code block, it's important to note that `playersWithTokenQuerySnapshot` is a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) object, not an array. While `forEach` is available on the `QuerySnapshot` object, to use normal Array methods like `.map` and `.reduce`, you need to use the `docs` property instead.

This makes your Cloud Function:

```
exports.getPlayerDataFromTokens = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const { tokens } = data;
  
  try {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    
    const playersGroupedByTokenArray = await Promise.all(
      tokens.map(token => getFootballPlayersWithToken(db, token))
    );
    
    // playersGroupedByTokenArray is an array of arrays
    // e.g. [[token1Player1, token1Player2], [token2Player1], [], ...]
    // flatten this array
    
    // Node 12+:
    // const playerArray = playersGroupedByTokenArray.flat()
    // Node 10+:
    const playerArray = [];
    playersGroupedByTokenArray.forEach(
      groupOfPlayers => playerArray.push(...groupOfPlayers)
    );
    
    return playerArray;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error finding players for one or more of these tokens: ", tokens.join(", "))
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "unknown",
      "Could not get players for one or more of the tokens provided",
      error.code || error.message
    );
  }
);
```

As shown in the above code block, for errors to be handled properly, you must wrap them in a [`HttpsError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/common_providers_https.httpserror) as [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors).

If a token would return only one player, you can tweak the above get players function to just the following and then edit your Cloud Function as needed:

```
/**
 * For the given token, return the matching player.
 */
async function getFootballPlayerByToken(db, token) {
  const playersWithTokenQuerySnapshot = await db
    .collection("Football_Player_Data")
    .where("Token", "==", token)
    .get();

  if (playersWithTokenQuerySnapshot.empty) {
    console.log("Given token did not match any players: ", token);
    return null; // or throw error
  }
  
  const playerDoc = playersWithTokenQuerySnapshot.docs[0];

  const { Token, Jersey_Number, Multiplier, PlayerID, Position, Team } = playerDoc.data();
  return { Token, Jersey_Number, Multiplier, PlayerID, Position, Team };
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! You helped clarify immensely

Comment: @ZachStruthers If this solved your question, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.